# Can an infinitive replace a comma in a conditional sentence: "If you need help to call somebody."

Tags: conditional-constructions, infinitives, punctuation

Are these two sentences the same sentences in meaning?

1. If you need help, call somebody.
2. If you need help to call somebody.

I want to know whether these two sentences are the same sentences in meaning.
Please, help me.

Comment: No. The second is only a fragment of a sentence. The to-infinitive phrase is not valid on its own as a main independent clause, which is required after the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

> If you need help to call somebody.

this sentence is indeed only a fragment of a full sentence.

Compare:

> I need help to find a telephone. (What kind of help do I need? For what reason do I need help?)
>   I need help to find a car. (I cannot find a car on my own)
>   I need help to call somebody. (I cannot call somebody on my own. In order to call somebody, I must be helped by someone or something)

You can disassemble the first sentence in this way:

> If you need help, call somebody. ->
>   Do you need help? Call somebody! (roughly the same meaning)

But you cannot disassemble the second (incomplete) sentence in a similar way:

> If you need help **to** call somebody. ->
>   Do you need help? **To** call somebody! (very weird-looking combination of sentences)

"Call somebody!" is an **[imperative sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English)** - it could be a command or a request, and in combination with an **if-clause** we can have a **[conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences)**:

> **If** you need help, call somebody"

"To call somebody!" is just an exclamation when used on its own. It does not work as an imperative sentence. And when used in a bigger sentence, it becomes an **infinitive clause**, which also cannot work as a command or request, so we cannot use it as an [apodosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) in a conditional sentence.